# Import image to Expression Engine from XML file

Tags: solspace, solspace-importer

I have purchased the Solspace Importer plugin to import xml data (properties data) into one of my client's website.

It managed to grab the data from the REAXML file manually but I'm having trouble displaying the given image url from the XML file into the site.

This is the example file:
[demo.slickdesign.com.au/rance-cms/mydesktop/residential_sample.xml](http://demo.slickdesign.com.au/rance-cms/mydesktop/residential_sample.xml)

My question is, how do I grab the image url from the XML file and map it into Expression Engine field?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Vic

Answer (score 1):

According to your XML file link, images are stored in an XML node's attribute. Eg:

```
<floorplan id="1" modTime="2009-01-01-12:30:00" url="http://www.realestate.com.au/tmp/floorplan1.gif" format="gif"/>
```

Unfortunately Importer cannot read XML node attributes, nor read self-closing XML nodes as of this writing.

The correct format to import the image URL in EE using Importer would be, eg.

```
<floorplan>http://www.realestate.com.au/tmp/floorplan1.gif</floorplan>
```

★ As additional/bonus information, if you're looking to import images into EE's **File field**, for example, you need to import the filename *only*, preceded by the target upload directory's ID. For example, if I want to import `my_file.jpg` into my upload directory 1, I would import this string:

```
{filedir_1}my_file.jpg
```

...followed by uploading my actual image file in the upload directory through FTP or other means.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand you well,
create new folder in *EE File upload preferences* with the specific path that you need 
later in your channel field you can pick that folder that you created with the specific path

More about image preference http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html